# Adding a Variable in For Loop Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is it possible to assign a variable and use that variable in the for loop statement?

I'm trying to place a collection of products in a blog without having to create a new for loop for each article that needs a collection.

What I've done is using the article's tags and splitting just before the collection handle so I can inject it in the for loop, but it's not quite working dynamically yet...

Here's what I've done.. I added in the article tags

```
collection_some-page-handle
```

Then in the article.liquid

```
    {% for tag in article.tags %}

      {% assign tagMap = tag | split: '_' %}
      {% if tagMap.first == 'collection' %}
        {% assign collectionName = tagMap.last %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{collectionName}} <!-- this shows the handle of the collection -->
    {% for product in collections.collectionName.products limit: 8%}
    <div class="productWrap">
            <a href="{{ product.url}}"><img src="{{ product.featured_image | product_img_url: 'medium' }}" alt=""></a>
          <a href="{{product.url}}"><p class="product_title" style="border-top:1px solid #efefef;">{{ product.title | split: ' - ' | first }}</p></a>
    </div>
    {%endfor%}
```

Now if i try to put the variable in the for loop it doesnt work, but of course if i put the actual handle it works. Is there a way to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `collections.collectionName` use `collections[collectionName]`.

This should fix your issue if your variable has the proper handle indeed.

To clarify when you use `collections.collectionName` you say - "Get me a collection that have handle collectionName`.

When you use `collections[collectionName]` you say - "Get me a collection using the variable `collectionName` as a handle."

Comment: That TOTALLY solved it! I did not know i could do that! It's perfect! 
Life saver